# Why it calculating Wrong Pisano period

Tags: c++, c++11

```
    long long fibonacci_fast(long long n) {

    long long a[n]{0};
    a[0]=0;
    a[1]=1;
    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
        a[i]=a[i-1]+a[i-2];

    return a[n];
}
```

and the fuction to calculate pisano period is

```
long long get_pisano_period(long long n,long long m){
    vector<long long> vec{0,1};

    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
        vec.push_back(fibonacci_fast(i)%m);


    long c{2};

    for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
    if((vec[i]!=0) && (vec[i+1]!=1)){
    c++;
    }}
    return c;
}
```

**In main function i m just outputing the output of get_pisano_period(n,m)**

Comment: `long long a[n]{0};` is a VLA compiler extension. Regardless, `a[n]` accesses it out of bounds, causing undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code tries to evaluate the Pisano period (the period with which the sequence of Fibonacci numbers **taken modulo n** repeats) given the modulo and what looks like a limit, but there are multiple issues.

- In `fibonacci_fast`, `a` is declared as a variable length array, a non-standard compiler extension in C++. It is also initialized, which would require another compiler extension even using C99. A `std::vector` should be used, in those cases.
- In the same function, `a` is also accessed out of bounds, in the loop (the last iteration) and when `a[n]` is returned.
- In `get_pisano_period` there's another source of undefined behaviour, the inner loop traverse `vec` up to `n + 1`, while its size is `i + 2`.

The logical errors are serious too.

- `fibonacci_fast` calculates the Fibonacci numbers **without** applying the modulo, so that those values are unbounded.
- The modulo is applied only before pushing the values returned by `fibonacci_fast` into `vec` inside the `get_pisano_period` function, but that generates the wrong sequence.
- Considering how it's used in `get_pisano_period`, the `_fast` part of the name `fibonacci_fast` is kind of a lie, since that function is called in the outer loop and every time it generates (and delete) all the numbers up to the increasing `i`.
- Moreover, the following loop checks *every* couple of subsequent values (let's leave out the already mentioned UB) and counts the couples which are not `{0, 1}`, while the function should check the *last two* values and *break* out of the loop as soon as it finds the repeating sequence.

If we only need the period and the sequence doesn't need to be stored for further uses, we can store and update only the two last numbers, without using a vector.

```
long long pisano_period(long long m, long long limit = 2048)
{
    long long fib_prev{0}, fib{1};

    if ( m < 2 )
        return 1;

    for (long long count{2}; count < limit; ++count)
    {
        // Evaluate the next Fibonacci number modulo m without any array or function call
        long long fib_next{
            (fib_prev + fib) % m
        };

        // If the sequence is repeating, the loop should stop.
        if ( fib == 0  &&  fib_next == 1 )
            return count - 1;

        // It stores only the two last values, so it has to update them.
        fib_prev = fib;
        fib = fib_next;
    }
    std::cerr << "Warning: limit reached.\n";
    return limit;
}
```

Testable [here](https://godbolt.org/z/yNznoJ).

Comment: Hey there, Thanks a lot for ur help :)